# Java and Autoit can't send key like TAB, ENTER or something else?

Tags: java, automation, autoit, jacob

I'm new to autoit and trying to integrate it with a java app. I can't make it send <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, it sends only plain text.

The code is this:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")){
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x86.dll";
        }
        else {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x64.dll";
        }
     try{ 
    File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("Skype", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone", AutoItX.SW_SHOW);
    x.winActivate("Skype");
    x.winWaitActive("Skype");
    x.sleep(2000);
    x.send("{TAB}!n" );
     }catch(Exception e){

   } 
}
```

I already tried:

- `x.controlSend("Window Title","text","","{ENTER}",false);`
- `x.send("{TAB}!n" );`
- `x.send("{TAB}n" );`

Comment: Where's your AutoIt code? A small functioning method would be nice. What is `"AutoItX"`?

Comment: Ah, you're using AutoItX4Java, aren't you? As a side note, you must take care to run all AutoIt code within a background thread, else it could freeze your Swing GUI.

Comment: Also, what is the overall goal of this code? If your desire is to push text into a Swing text component, then there may be better ways to do this.

Comment: Yes i use AutoItX4Java, and i know the problem with the freezes and im working to fix that but now i have to fix the autoit script, thy for the advice

Comment: The goal is to auto login on skype presing only a button this is a part of a app for auto login on some sites and some apps and it must send thins like ENTER, TAB, ALT

Comment: I would do the complete login stuff in autoit and just call/start the autoit script from your java program.

Comment: i tink that selenium is more ok for web pages i need autoit only for windows apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with true or false thy to Milos for giving me the solution

```
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String sql="select * from app_1 where id_user_main=?";  
    String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")){
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x86.dll";
        }
        else {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x64.dll";
        }
     try{ 
    File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("Skype", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone", AutoItX.SW_SHOW);
    x.winWait("Skype");
    x.winActivate("Skype");
    x.winWaitActive("Skype");
    x.sleep(2000);
    x.send("{TAB}!n", false );

     }catch(Exception e){

   } 
}
```

Thy all for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing WinWait.

Try this

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")){
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x86.dll";
        }
        else {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x64.dll";
        }
     try{ 
    File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("Skype", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone", AutoItX.SW_SHOW);
    x.winWait("Skype");
    x.winActivate("Skype");
    x.winWaitActive("Skype");
    x.sleep(2000);
    x.send("{TAB}!n", false );
     }catch(Exception e){

   } 
}
```

Comment: Thy, but still the same problem it sends {TAB}!n as a text

Comment: @Tehnic added 0 to the send function.  x.send("{TAB}!n", 0 ); This will make it send special keys. set it to 1 if you want to send them raw, like its happening now.

Comment: @Tehnic also try this x.send("{TAB}{ALT}n", 0 );

Comment: Thy Milos that was it i did it but not with number with true or false         x.send("{TAB}!n", false ); new is ok thy

Comment: Great, I'll add that to the answer and  feel free to select my answer if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: Cool ad the answer thy very much